# Is try to vs is trying to

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

I was taking a quiz at Coursera and there was a sentence

- What kitchen counter may be a better environment to help someone who is try to manage their weight?

I was confused – shouldn't this be "is trying to"? Can someone, please, explain.

Comment: Just an error, probably a typo. Totally ungrammatical.

Comment: Really gibberish, nonsensical.